# Search within json using php

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
$string= file_get_contents("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.23.1/data/en_US/champion.json");
$array = json_decode($string, true);
foreach($array ["key"] as $key) {
    if($key == '412') {
        echo $key['id'];
    }
}
?>
```

Basically what i'm trying to do here is search for the key which is basically the numeric version of the id, using the key i'm trying to find the correct string id in the huge json array, but i'm facing some struggles as i'm not sure how to do this.

In http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.23.1/data/en_US/champion.json if you search for 412 (twice on the second find on CTRL f) you will see `"key":"412"`
well i want the id which is a entry up from it which in this case is "Thresh" (`"id":"Thresh"`) (What i want returned is just Thresh). Hopefully i was as clear as possible. Thanks

Comment: I think it should be `$jsonArray ["data"] as $key`

Comment: @AlonEitan still doesn't work

Comment: @PedroLobito I just need a solution to this really, i just need to find the id from the key. 412 = Thresh for example

Comment: @JL I just posted one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop `['data']` not `["key"]`, which is inside `['data']`.

```
$string= file_get_contents("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.23.1/data/en_US/champion.json");
$array = json_decode($string, true);
foreach($array['data'] as $data) {
    if($data['key'] == '412') {
        echo $data['id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Literally just figured this out myself a second ago, exactly how i solved this. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. 
If you face any logical matter, I will explain it to you.

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.23.1/data/en_US/champion.json");
$jsonArray = json_decode($string, true);

foreach($jsonArray ["data"] as $key) {
    if($key['key'] == '412') {
        echo $key['id'];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional level of nesting you need to consider. `$array['data']` is itself an associative array with keys like `Aatrox`. Each of these keys as an associative array inside of it.  It is within that nested array you must look..

```
foreach($array['data'] as $element_name => $element_data) {
    $key = $element_data['key'];
    if ($key === '412') {
        echo $element_data['id'];
    };
}
```

If you are going to be working with a data set like this, you might consider keeping a map of `key` values to `id` values, as it looks like the data is structured to enable fast lookup by the `id`.